# Why am I getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in this simple forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create buttons using a forEach loop and to test that I setup everything correctly I put in a the alert dumbly function but when I run my code I get a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". I'm not sure why this is happening since shouldn't it only run 4 times since there's only 4 items in the array?

```js
const btns = [
  {
    color: "blue",
    id: "blue",
  },
  {
    color: "red",
    id: "red",
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    id: "yellow",
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    id: "green",
  },
];

function createPlayerBtns() {
  btns.forEach(alert);

  function alert() {
    alert("hello");
  }
}

createPlayerBtns();
```

Comment: Don't call your function `alert`. The problem is you're shadowing the built-in global, so when you call `alert('hello')` it's not calling that but the function it's inside. Hence, infinite recursion and stack overflow.

Comment: If you want to call the real `alert`, use `window.alert("hello")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
const btns = [
  { color: 'blue', id: 'blue', },
  { color: 'red', id: 'red', },
  { color: 'yellow', id: 'yellow', },
  { color: 'green', id: 'green', },
];

btns.forEach(btn => alert(JSON.stringify(btn)));
```